# Entity Framework - Add existing foreign key to class structure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship, code-first

I have class like this:

```
public class Bundle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public Child Something { get; set; }
}
```

EF created a table like this:

```
| Id | CreateDate | Something_Id |
```

What i'm trying now, is to add the Something_Id foreign key to the class. I don't want to load the whole 'Something'-object just to get it's Id. However EF demands a DB-update and the db update with the manually added integer property 'Something_Id' fails because Something_Id is not nullable. How can i add this foreign key to the class structure without loosing data or relations?

Comment: did you configure the relationship Bundle->Child to use your exposed property Something_Id? Otherwise it will expect it to be another property and use another naming convention for the FK (else there would be no migration to apply, since the schema is identical)

Comment: Yes i tried with naming convention (SomethingId) and with data-annotation -> [ForeignKey], it threw an exception 'Context has changed..' and on DB-update it said "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ComplexId', table 'VGLSY.dbo.ClientBids'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: the column that raised the exception is on table ClientBids, not Bundle, also the column name is ComplexId, not Something_Id. I would assume you made differences to another table as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok stupid mistake on my side. The null-exception actually gave the hint. One entry in the database did not have a foreign-key set, therefore the class structure was not allowed to be non-nullable and the update failed.